# MS Access Form: How to show all records that reference current record

Tags: ms-access

I have a form showing *Customers*. Now I would like to also display all *Orders* that the currently open customer has made.
The *Order* table has a foreign key to *Customer*.

I have tried using a list box with Multi Select set to Simple, but somehow it shows me all Orders instead of just the ones of the current customer.

More Details:
My list box has

```
Control Source: ID
Row Source: SELECT customer.id, order.info FROM customer 
            INNER JOIN order ON customer.ID = order.customer_id
```

If I set the Multi Select to None it always marks the first Order that matches the current customer, but not all matching orders.

Can someone point me in the right direction?
Thank you.

P.S. I don't necessarily want the list to be functional for the creation of a new Customer. If it would also work then that's a bonus.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your form is bound to Customers table, then you need to add code to the form's Current event:

```
lstOrders.RowSource = "SELECT id, info FROM order WHERE customer_id = " & Me.id
lstOrders.Requery
```

The list box (called lstOrders) should have its column count set to 2. If you don't want to see the order.id column then set the "Column widths" property to 0 (this will set the width of the first column to 0 and let the second column, order.info, fill the remaining width of the list). Set the "Bound column" to 1 - this means that the "value" of the list box will be the order.id